# Why this equality is correct?

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving an integral with wolfram alpha and at the last point it said this is equivalent to this:
$$-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac 1 {\sqrt2 \tan x}\right)=\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2\tan x) $$
Why?

Comment: Can you please give the wolfram Alpha link? (As a context)

Comment: This inequality is not true. Check $x=0$. !

Comment: I put good odds that WA didn't say that; you're just ignoring relevant context. (e.g. the 'constant of integration')

Comment: @Qwerty : Why do you call it an "inequality"? (ok, I'll take that to be a Freudian slip.) If one takes $A=B$ to mean "$A$ is equivalent to $B$", then the equivalence is true, if "equivalent" means they both have the same derivative. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

It is not: for one thing, $\arctan(-t)=-\arctan t$, but the map $t\mapsto \dfrac1t$ preserves the sign. The correct version would be $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2\tan x}\right)+\arctan(\sqrt2\tan x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)\cdot\frac\pi2\qquad \text{for }x\ne k\pi$$ which comes straight from the identity for $y\ne0$ $$\arctan y+\arctan\dfrac1y=\operatorname{sign}(y)\cdot \dfrac\pi2$$

The reason why wolframalpha (or someone) said that thing is that it/he is just looking at some primitive of the integrand and hence ignoring constants (good) or locally constant functions (not so good). It is true that both of those can be considered equivalent primitives, as long as you are not integrating through an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The software told you these are "equivalent", and so they are, but we need to understand what the appropriate kind of "equivalence" is.  If we call two functions "equivalent" precisely if they have the same derivative, then these are equivalent.

Two functions have the same derivative if and only if the difference between them is piecewise constant, i.e. constant on every connected interval in their common domain. One way to see that these are equivalent is to differentiate them and see that their derivatives are equal.

If $x=\dfrac\pi4$ then $\tan x =1$, and the right side of the proposed equivalence is $\arctan \sqrt 2.$ The left side is $-\arctan \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}.$ These are not the same number. In a right triangle, let us call the two obtuse angles $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ We have
$$
\tan = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}
$$
but **the "opposite" for $\alpha$ is the "adjacent" for $\beta$ and vice-versa.** So $\tan\alpha$ and $\tan\beta$ are each other's reciprocals. Let $m=\tan\alpha;$ then $\dfrac 1 m = \tan \beta.$  Since $\alpha+\beta=\text{a right angle} = \dfrac\pi2,$ we have
\begin{align}
\alpha + \beta & = \text{a right angle} = \frac \pi 2 \\[10pt]
\text{or in other words}\qquad \arctan m + \arctan\frac 1 m & = \text{a right angle} = \frac \pi 2.
\end{align}
So
$$
\frac\pi2 - \arctan \frac 1 m = \arctan m,
$$
or, if you like
$$
\text{constant} - \arctan\frac 1 m = \arctan m.
$$

(If the angles are negative, then the "constant" must be $\dfrac{-\pi} 2.$ I'll leave that as an exercise.)